# Database choice for saving and querying stock prices

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, cassandra, nosql

I'm currently receiving 2000 prices per second from a stock exchange and need to save those in an appropriate database. My current choice is PostgresQL which is way too slow. I need to save those prices (ticks) in an aggregated form like OHLC. So if I want to save D1 data for instance, I need to first get the previous D1 record for the stock from the database, check if the high or low price has changed and set a new close price and then save it to the database again. This is taking forever and is not possible with Postgres. I don't want to save the OHLC data, I prefer querying (aggregating) those in real-time.

So my requirements are:

- persistance
- fast writes (currently 2k per second, up to 10k)
- queries, e.g. aggregating OHLC data in real-time (50-100 per second)
- adoptable to any modern programming language without writing raw queries (SDK for Python or JS for that database)
- deployable on AWS or GCP without hassle

I was thinking about Apache Cassandra. I'm not familiar with Cassandra, are powerful queries like OHLC one possible? Are there any alternatives to Cassandra?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what I've understood from your question, I believe Cassandra should easily fit your use-case.

Regarding your requirements:

- **persistence** : Cassandra will not only persist your data but also cover redundancy with minimal configuration;
- **fast writes** : this is what Cassandra is most optimized for and while the exact throughput depends on a lot of factors, in general Cassandra will manage writes measured in the thousands/sec/core; Also, the eventual number o writes is not really relevant as Cassandra can scale linearly with no real penalty so 5k,10k, 100k or more are all doable;
- **adaptability** : Cassandra has official drivers for the most common languages(Python, C family, NodeJs, Java, Ruby, PHP, Scala) as well as community developed ones for more languages ([list of divers](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/drivers.html));
- **deployable** : It's very easy to deploy in the cloud. You can chose to deploy it manually on independent instances or maybe use a managed Cassandra cluster (AWS has one, it's called '*AWS Keyspaces*', Datastax(the company driving most of the development behind Cassandra) has one called '*Astra*' and there are even more possible solutions. Given that Cassandra is one of the major players when it comes to big-data storage finding a place for you DB in the cloud should be easy.

I have only mentioned 4 of the 5 requirements. That is because when talking about reading, things get more complex and a larger discussion is needed.

500-100 reads/s given the 2k+ writes per second seem to be in line with the general idea of Cassandra being optimized for write intensive tasks. In Cassandra the way you will model your tables will dictate how well things can work. For a task like you have described my first thoughts are:

1. You bucket each stock per day => you get a partition with around 30k rows (1 update/s for 8 trading hours) and a size of under 0.2MB (30k * 4B). This would be well within the recommended values and clearly under the worst case scenario ones;
2. when you need the aggregated data you have 2 options:

2a. You read the partition as is and aggregate it application side (what I would recommend);

2b. You implement an "*User-Defined Aggregate*" function on your database that will do the work ([docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/functions.html)). This should be doable although I won't guarantee it. Apart from being harder to implement, the problem is that putting this kind of extra workload on the DB might not be want you want given your apparent use-case. Let me explain: I'd expect your reading load to be most active during certain times, (before, during and after trading hours) with times when the load is lighter. Depending on your architecture, you could have multiple application instances up during peak times, and then scale them back during off-peak in order to lower costs. While applications can be easily scaled up and down on cloud providers like AWS and GC. Cassanadra cannot be scaled up and down like this (5 nodes in the morning, 3 in the night and so on)(well it could but it's not designed to and would be a terrible decision). So moving as much of the non-constant workload to the application seems the best idea;

3. (Optional) have a worker that at the end of the day/trading day will aggregate the values for each stock and save them to another table so that when looking at historic data it will be easier. This data could even be bucketed by week, month or even year depending on how much space the aggregated data takes.

You could also add Spark and Kafka in front of Casandra for a more powerful approach to the real-time aggregation but we should't deviate that much from the question at hand.

Cassandra is very powerful with the right modeling and the right architecture. At first glance what you need seems to be a good fit for Cassandra however as powerful as it can be, as bad as it can get if you use it in ways it wasn't designed to. I hope this answer puts you on a path into making the right decision.

Cheers.